Haskell fix structural sharing or not
In this wiki about the use of the fix function for recursion in haskell, they define two ways of defining fix.
One with structural sharing:
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = let {x = f x} in x

One without structural sharing:
fix :: (a -> a) -> a
fix f = f (fix f)

Now I don't really understand why the first one is with structural sharing and the other one not. I have been staring at the expansions of each one with the factorial function but I cannot understand where I see that one has structural sharing and the other not.
Structural sharing:
 fix fact'
= let rec = fact' rec in rec
= let rec = (\rec' n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec' (n-1)) rec in rec
= let rec = (\n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)) in rec
= let rec = (\n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)) in 
   \n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)
= let rec = (\n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)) in 
   \n -> if n == 0 then 1
        else n * (if n-1 == 0 then 1 else (n-1) * rec (n-2))
= ...

(For this one, I don't understand the last step well, is it a fusion of multiple steps?)
No structural sharing:
 fix fact'
= let rec = fact' rec in rec
= let rec = (\rec' n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec' (n-1)) rec in rec
= let rec = (\n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)) in rec
= let rec = (\n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)) in 
   \n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)
= let rec = (\n -> if n == 0 then 1 else n * rec (n-1)) in 
   \n -> if n == 0 then 1
        else n * (if n-1 == 0 then 1 else (n-1) * rec (n-2))
= ...


I don't think you can easily observe structural sharing using your fact'. Try instead fix (\xs -> 1:xs). Before doing that, I'd recommend considering f () = 1 : f () vs g () = let xs = 1:xs in xs. Here g uses constant space, f does not. (Yes, it's rather subtle)

@chi, what would f or g be in your example? What could I use to test it?

The equations I wrote in my comment are the definition of functions f,g :: () -> [Int]. You can use them in a .hs file (but I'd include there their type signatures as well). I guess you could test them trying to print head $ drop 100000 $ f () and its g () analogous.

Note that there is no real way to detect if structural sharing is used or not inside Haskell -- the two programs are equivalent, and only differ in their performance. When learning Haskell, I'd say it's best to avoid reasoning on these low-level details, and just accept "it's a more efficient fix". Just pretend fix is defined in the most convenient way, e.g. fix f = f (fix f) and use that to reason about programs. After mastering Haskell one can then look under the hood and see how low-level pointers implement the second fix more efficiently.

The difference is where the recursion really is. In the first case, fix creates a recursive object x, but fix itself is not recursive. The result is. Contrary, in the latter case, it is fix that is recursive independently from f. There is therefore no opportunity for structural sharing, because there is no reference to be shared (except the fix function pointer).
A better example, as suggested in the comments, is fix (1:). The first variant expands to expected let x = 1:x in x where the reference x is shared with the underlying object (might be more visible with 1:2:x tho). Expansion of it would look more or less like

x (subst x := 1:x)
1:x (subst x := 1:x)
1:1:x (subst x := 1:x)
1:1:1:x ...

In the second case you end up with 1 : fix (1:). The fix (1:) part is a call to a function, and it is not obviously clear to the compiler that it will evaluate to exactly the same thing as the whole expression. It is also not really a value yet. Therefore, even if reduced to ANF as let x = fix (1:) in 1 : x, there is no direct indication that any two things here are the same and can share a place in memory. Evaluation would also expose another difference:

fix (1:) (reduce)
1 : fix (1:) (reduce)
1 : 1 : fix (1:) (reduce)
1 : 1 : 1 : fix (1:) ...

As seen, a difference is that in the first case we used substitution and in the second we had reduction. Substitution deals with references, which is in the very spirit of sharing, whereas reduction not really.

(all of that could be optimized sometimes, but it's another topic)

I don't know much about haskell but what is the object in "let x = 1:x in x where the reference x is shared with the underlying object "? Also I am not sure I understood why in one case, fix is recursive and in the other case, it is the result of fix that is recursive.

@roi_saumon Very roughly, let x = 1:x is implemented with a pointer. In pseudo-C, I'd write node x = { .value=1 , .next=&x }; using a pointer to itself. By contrast let f () = 1 : f () is a recursive function which allocates a new node at each call, because the result of functions is not cached and reused. The resulting pointer graphs are observationally equivalent, but one is very small, the other is infinite.

Alright. I will have to think about it. Originally I asked myself this question in the context of memoization where I read that fix was used and I was wondering if memoization was the result of structural sharing

@roi_saumon As a rule of thumb, a variable used in an expression (like x) is a reference to a single pre-allocated value, and can therefore be shared if the variable is used more than once. So in let {x = f x} in x, we have two uses of the variable x (once in the sub-expression f x and once in the in part of the let ... in ... construct), which can be shared. A function application like f x or fix f generally allocates a new value when it is evaluated, which thus could only be shared by binding it to a variable. In fix f = f (fix f) there's no variable for the fix f part.

Haskell does not memorize a lot. Sharing is a completely independent feature, though memorization might help applying it sometimes.

Let us take fixStruct f = let x = f x in x and fixDirect f = f (fixDirect f), and look at how fixDirect (1:) and fixStruct (1:) work in a bit more detail. We're going to do this by representing evaluation as a sequence of graphs. There are three kinds of nodes in this graph: names, thunks, and constructors. Name nodes contain a pointer to either a thunk (if the value of the name hasn't been fully worked out yet) or a constructor (if we know what it ought to be by now). Thunks represent a pending function application; they have two children, one for the function being applied and one for the thing it's applied to. Constructor nodes are labeled with the appropriate data constructor, and have one child for each field of that data constructor. (For the purposes of this discussion, we'll say that bare lambdas are also constructor nodes to keep things simple.)
Let's start with fixDirect (1:). The graph starts out looking like this:
thunk{} -arg-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
| fun
v
name{fixDirect} -> constructor{\f -> f (fixDirect f)}

Each node in this graph is shown with the format type{label}; for example, name{fixDirect} denotes a name node with label fixDirect. Children are shown with arrows. For thunks, the arrows are labeled either fun or arg as appropriate; for constructors, the arrows will be labeled field0, field1, etc.
As evaluation proceeds, we will be replacing thunk nodes with the result of one step of evaluation. Thunk nodes can only proceed if its function child is a constructor, so let's look up the name fixDirect and replace the name node with its value.
thunk{} -arg-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
       \
        `---------. fun
                   v
name{fixDirect} -> constructor{\f -> f (fixDirect f)}

Now the thunk has a lambda as its function, so we can evaluate it by creating a new subgraph with the body of the lambda, where each occurrence of the parameter points to the existing argument subgraph.
thunk{} -fun-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
| arg          ^
v             /
thunk{} -arg-'
| fun
v
name{fixDirect} -> constructor{\f -> f (fixDirect f)}                    

Take a moment to make sure you understand how this graph corresponds to the body f (fixDirect f) of the lambda we've just applied. In any case, the top level thunk is now again an application of a lambda, so we can again produce the body of the lambda with a pointer to the argument subgraph in place of the parameter.
constructor{:} -field0-> constructor{1}
| field1
v
thunk{} -arg-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
| fun
v
name{fixDirect} -> constructor{\f -> f (fixDirect f)}

At this point, the subgraph in field 1 is identical to the graph we started with, so the next few evaluation steps should look very familiar. First we do name resolution:
constructor{:} -field0-> constructor{1}
| field1
v
thunk{} -arg-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
       \
        `---------. fun
                   v
name{fixDirect} -> constructor{\f -> f (fixDirect f)}

Then produce a subgraph for the body of the lambda with pointers to the argument as appropriate:
constructor{:} -field0-> constructor{1}
| field1
v
thunk{} -fun-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
| arg          ^
v             /
thunk{} -arg-'
| fun
v
name{fixDirect} -> constructor{\f -> f (fixDirect f)}

Apply the lambda:
constructor{:} -field0-> constructor{1}
| field1
v
constructor{:} -field0-> constructor{1}
| field1
v
thunk{} -arg-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
| fun
v
name{fixDirect} -> constructor{\f -> f (fixDirect f)}

...and repeat ad infinitum, leading to an infinite graph with a very regular structure:
constructor{:} -field0-> constructor{1}
| field1
v
constructor{:} -field0-> constructor{1}
| field1
v
constructor{:} -field0-> constructor{1}
| field1
v
constructor{:} -field0-> constructor{1}
| field1
v
...

Perfectly cromulent! Okay, now let's do fixStruct (1:). The starting graph is very similar.
thunk{} -arg-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
| fun
v
name{fixStruct} -> constructor{\f -> let x = f x in x}

Name resolution as usual:
thunk{} -arg-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
       \
        `---------. fun
                   v
name{fixStruct} -> constructor{\f -> let x = f x in x}

Apply the lambda:
name{x} -> thunk{} -fun-> constructor{\v -> 1:v}
^         / arg
 `-------'
name{fixStruct} -> constructor{\f -> let x = f x in x}

This step is the key one to understand, as it is the primary difference between the two kinds of fix. There are two critical pieces to notice here. First: the top-level thing we're evaluating now has a cycle! This is the first time we've seen that. Second: the top-level graph we're evaluating now no longer includes any references to fixStruct, even inside the bodies of unapplied lambdas. The part of the graph that defines fixStruct is still hanging around, but it's dead code (or dead graph, I guess).
In any case, the only existing thunk is an application of a lambda, so we can do our usual thing, replacing it with the body of the lambda with pointers to the arguments.
name{x} -> constructor{:} -field0-> 1
^         / field1
 `-------'
name{fixStruct} -> constructor{\f -> let x = f x in x}

At this point, there are no thunks left, despite having done only a finite amount of evaluation. The resulting graph is perforce finite, though I hope you can see that there's a real sense in which it represents the same infinite value as the infinite graph from fixDirect.
There are concepts here (in these graphs) that are not easily captured by standard syntactic representations of evaluation sequences. This is part of why many people find it difficult to see the distinction between the two definitions of fix just by looking at traditional evaluation traces. You really need to get into some of the internal implementation details before you can find the difference.

+1  This is an excellent answer that very clearly explains the underlying issue.  @roi_saumon, I encourage you to honestly study the steps marked "Take a moment to make sure you understand..." and "This step is the key one to understand...".  (It took me a literal minute to understand the first step; after that, the second was easier.)

I’ll name the two versions of fix unshared and shared.
unshared :: forall a. (a -> a) -> a
unshared f = f (unshared f)

shared :: forall a. (a -> a) -> a
shared f = let x = f x in x
-- or:
shared f = x where x = f x

We often use fix with function types, that is, specialised to ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b. However, the type (a -> a) -> a is a little more general, to support lazy data structures, and I think this can illustrate the difference nicely.
For example, here’s a function that we can pass to fix to make a stream of characters ([Char] a.k.a. String), which uses trace to show each time it’s called and allocates a new list cell (:).
import Debug.Trace (trace)

stars :: [Char] -> [Char]
stars again = trace "(new)" ('*' : again)

If we load this in GHCi, we can observe the difference between shared stars and unshared stars:
λ test generator = putStrLn (take 5 generator)

λ test (shared stars)
(new)
*****

λ test (unshared stars)
(new)
*(new)
*(new)
*(new)
*(new)
*

That is, shared stars only allocates one stream that repeatedly yields the same value, while unshared stars repeatedly allocates a new stream each time again is called.
In case you’re familiar with a language such as Python that has a notion of generators, it’s effectively the same as the difference between these two definitions.
from itertools import islice

def shared_stars():
    print("(new)")
    while True:
        yield '*'

def unshared_stars():
    print("(new)")
    yield '*'
    yield from unshared_stars()

def test(generator):
    for char in islice(generator, 5):
        print(char, end="")
    print()

>>> test(shared_stars())
(new)
*****
>>> test(unshared_stars())
(new)
*(new)
*(new)
*(new)
*(new)
*

So indeed shared is just unshared with a bit of memoisation applied. You can even work it out equationally.

By definition:
fix f = f (fix f)


We can give a name to the subexpression fix f.
fix f = f x where x = fix f


Because fix f = f x, we can replace fix f with f x in the definition of x.
fix f = f x where x = f x


Finally, because x = f x, we can replace f x with x in the definition of fix.
fix f = x where x = f x

=
fix f = let x = f x in x



